Apply dynamic glint effect img to other partially transparent img using css
I want to apply an animating glinting effect to certain images on my web page.  The images are all randomly shaped and have transparent parts.  I want the glint to only be applied to the opaque parts of these images.  I have prepared the glint itself in an animated .webp file; it contains moving wavy half-transparent streaks of colors.  It is complex enough that I do not want to create it with css (if that is even possible).
My attempt at this was to stack two images on top of each other with position: absolute;.  The lower image is the one to be glinted and the upper one the glint itself.  And then apply mix-blend-mode: lighten; (or overlay, or whatever turns out best) to the glint image.  This works, but the glint doesn't contain itself to only the opaque parts of the image.
Now I wonder if this effect can be realized with plain css at all?  The alternative is to prepare pre-glinted versions of all relevant images, but due to file size and maintenance concerns I'd rather not do that.
The code I have so far is:


.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000080;
}
.icon .type {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    object-fit: none;
    object-position: 0px 0px; /* its a css image sprite */
    z-order: 10;
}
.icon .glint {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-order: 11;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
<div class="icon">
    <img class="type" src="https://omeo.one/images/icons.png">
    <img class="glint" src="https://omeo.one/images/glint.webp">
</div>



The icons are just regular 24x24 images arranged in an image sprite (link; the lower half is what I use now as 'glinted' version, but I want to make it animated).  I haven't yet finalized the glint image, but I've uploaded a proof of concept (link).  I first tried to upload the glint webp image file but StackOverflow refused to take it?  To see it in context, my site (OMEO) now uses a static pre-glinted image, next to the item drop downs.  For the curious: I want to replicate the Minecraft glinting effect for enchanted items.

Please create a runnable snippet (including images we can actually see) which demonstrates the problem.

@AHaworth: I've updated my post with the extra details.

FYI: You can use Lorem Picsum a.k.a. picsum.photos to post an example with real images. Use the <> button in SO's editor to make your code a runnable example.

@PeterPointer: thanks for that; I didn't yet know about code snippets on SO.  Updated my post to use it instead of a codepen link.  The picsum photos site is also nice!  But in this case I need images which are partially transparent.

If you want the glint to "contain itself to only the opaque parts of the image" then mask is the answer. I also changed the imgs to pseudo elements to tidy up the HTML code a bit.


.icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-image: url('https://omeo.one/images/icons.png');
  background-position: calc(-24px * (var(--index, 1) - 1)) 0px;
}

.icon::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-image: url('https://omeo.one/images/glint.webp');
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  mask-image: url(https://omeo.one/images/icons.png);
  mask-position: calc(-24px * (var(--index, 1) - 1)) 0px;
}

.icon:nth-child(2) {
  background: #800;
}

.icon:nth-child(3) {
  background: #080;
}

.icon:nth-child(4) {
  background: #008;
}

.icon:nth-child(5) {
  background: #888;
}
<div class="icon" style="--index:1;"></div>
<div class="icon" style="--index:2;"></div>
<div class="icon" style="--index:3;"></div>
<div class="icon" style="--index:4;"></div>
<div class="icon" style="--index:5;"></div>




Nice find!  And I also like the use of the css vars override in the style attribute on the elements themselves; a nice technique that surely enables interesting possibilities elsewhere in the future.  I did sweat a bit about CanIUse's verdict on mask-image (because I preferably want to be ~10 years backward compatible with old browsers), but it is also supported there when prefixing it with -webkit-.

If backward compatibility is an issue, you can try using SVG or canvas (with canvas you need to draw each frame of the glint manually though). 10 year old browsers seem a bit ambitious, considering how fast the web technology has been growing recent years, 10 years ago is like a lawless jungle (looking nervously at IE).

For IE I make an exception by ignoring it :)  And the site I work on is aimed at a demographic with potentially potatoes for computers and smartphones, and I don't want those to be left behind.  So far I've managed fine I think with the compatibility, but then again: the code and css for my site isn't really that ambitious.

I've looked into this a bit more, and specifying a white background image somewhere in the stack isn't even needed, as long as the mask-image is set up correctly.  In context of my div set-up <div 'icon'><img 'type'><img 'glint'></div> I omit all background colors, specify a regular object-position for img 'type' (img sprite coords), and put the mix-blend-mode, mask-image and mask-position on img 'glint'.

@CarlColijn Yes, the background is just for demonstration purpose. For this to work you only need 1) the main image, 2) the effect image (glint), 3) the mask image (in this case is the main image itself), and 4) matching the coordinates of the image(s) and the mask correctly when using sprites instead of individual images.

The new css (and glint img) is now live and looking great; thanks again!  I've also changed the img sprite to be 1 row high only instead of a grid, so I've also updated your answer to reflect this (since it links to the live images).  It should go through once my edit is out of the review queue.

mix-blend-mode lighten is the right idea.
However, outside the opaque part of the image there is nothing to 'lighten' against. Putting a background on the image that is white will ensure that on lighten white will be what shows.


<style>
  .icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000080;
  }
  
  .icon .type {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    object-fit: none;
    object-position: 0px 0px;
    /* it's a css image sprite */
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .icon .glint {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 11;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  }
</style>
<div class="icon">
  <img class="type" src="https://omeo.one/images/icons.png">
  <img class="glint" src="https://omeo.one/images/glint.webp">
</div>



Note: I have not heard of z-order so have changed it to z-index, though it makes no difference in this example as the glint is positioned after and absolutely relative to the image.

Thanks for that!  That's indeed the effect I'm after.  But what if I told you I do not want to have a white background behind the icon... :)  It should work on any background color actually.  And that z-order is my bad; I added it in afterwards again from memory (I'm not a native web dev if you can tell), and it seemed to work, but that's indeed due to the element stacking order itself.
